# A valid use of IS_ERR() macro

Tags: c, linux, macros, compiler-construction, linux-device-driver

I was creating a simple driver and came across a sample code which does this

```
  if(IS_ERR(c = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "char")))
  {
   ...
  }
```

I tried to know what is behind IS_ERR() and i saw this
It defines as,
...

```
#define IS_ERR_VALUE(x) unlikely((x) >= (unsigned long)-MAX_ERRNO)
static inline long __must_check IS_ERR(const void *ptr)
{
      return IS_ERR_VALUE((unsigned long)ptr);
}
```

and what is this 'unlikely' thing?

Answer (score 3):

Reference: http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/LikelyUnlikely

likely() and unlikely() are compiler directives to re-arrange generated code for conditional branching in such a way that best utilizes processor's pipeline.

if(likely(condition)): This condition will be "true" in most of the cases, so compiler should arrange the branching in such a way that code under 'then' statement has least jumps and pipeline flushes.

if (unlikely(condition)): This condition will be "false" in most of the cases, so compiler should arrange the branching in such a way that code under 'else' statement has least jumps and pipeline flushes.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions of `unlikely()` is in [`include/linux/compiler.h`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/compiler.h), here is one of them:

```
# ifndef likely
#  define likely(x) (__builtin_constant_p(x) ? !!(x) : __branch_check__(x, 1))
# endif
# ifndef unlikely
#  define unlikely(x)   (__builtin_constant_p(x) ? !!(x) : __branch_check__(x, 0))
# endif
```

Those macros are optimization hints for compilers.